# Type of a function variable in Go

Tags: types, go, function-pointers, higher-order-functions

I want to write a function which takes a pointer to any type of function. I could do:

```
func myFunc(f interface{})
```

...but that would allow non-function values. Is there any way I can restrict the type to any function?

Comment: There is no "supertype" of all function types, except `interface{}`, so this is the best you can do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you literally mean *any* function, you can either do a type switch (which would be specific):

```
switch v.(type) {
case func() int:
case func() string:
}
```

Or you could use the `reflect` package to determine the type:

```
if reflect.TypeOf(v).Kind() != reflect.Func {
    // error here
}
```

This is a runtime solution. Other than that, there's nothing else you can do. The downside about this is the compiler won't stop someone from passing a non-function value.

Personally I would avoid doing this, and I would expect a specific func prototype, like:

```
func myFunc(f func() string)
```

With this you're less likely to have errors when the compiler knows what the types are.

Answer (score 1):

The concept of "any function" *can* be constructed in Go in two steps:

```
type MotherOfAllFuncs func()
```

The next step is to to wrap *any* function in a closure, which, as an anonymous type, is assignment compatible with `MotherOfAllFuncs`.

```
func() {
        anyFunction(with, any, parameters)
}
```

---

```
package main

import "fmt"

type f func()

func g(f f) {
        f()
}

func h(i int) {
        fmt.Println(21 * i)
}

func i() {
        fmt.Println(314)
}

func main() {
        g(func() { h(2) })
        g(func() { i() })
}
```

[Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/GDs546R-c4)

---

Output:

```
42
314
```

Comment: I see where you're coming from, and that technically works, but it's really hack-y. If I'm doing that, I might as well do the reflection check inside the accepting function.

Answer (score 0):

Functions are [first class citizens](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_citizen) in Go. So they can be passed to and returned from functions like any other type.

You can define your function to take function as its argument.

Read more - [First class functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_function) and [First class functions in Go](http://blog.golang.org/first-class-functions-in-go-and-new-go).

Comment: My use case is more like this: I want to have a function, `func takesFunc(f func())` and be able to pass in ANY function (regardless of argument and return types). What you're saying will allow me to accept one particular TYPE of function (ie, `func(int) int` or `func(bool) (string, int)`), but not any arbitrary function type.